# Include a module template into an other module template

Tags: 8, theming

I'm working on a Drupal 8 project and in my module X twig template I need to include the template of an other module Y. All what I found in documentation is how to call a template inside other template in theme [see here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/including-part-template)

I've tried in my `twig-of-module-X.html.twig` file:

```
{% include 'modules/Y/templates/twig-of-module-Y.html.twig' %}
```

but doesn't work!
Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Include the template file with its namespace:

`{% include '@modulename/template_file.html.twig' %}`

`{# @modulename refers to 'path_to_module/templates' #}`

Drupal provides a `@namespace` for Twig based on the machine name of every module and every theme. The `@namespace` points to the `templates` sub-directory of that module or theme.

Comment: Thanks bro! please update your answer use {% %} instead of {{ }}

Comment: And also @modulename refers to path_to_module/templates so some_subdir means templates directory sub_dirs it works for me thanks :)

Comment: should not use templates in path it's included in twig namespace (@modulename) `{% include '@modulename/if_a_subdir_exist_in_templates_directory/template_file.html.twig' %}`

Comment: Edited once again, hope it is correct now

Comment: When using a twig template from one module in another can you still populate it with vars from the templates module somehow?

Comment: @dibs Yeah! you could do it using `with` keyword. example: 

`{% include '@modulename/template-file.html.twig'  with {'var1': 'Hello world'} %}`

And in template-file.html.twig:

`<h1>{{ var1 }}</h1>`

Comment: @MiharbKH I see you can manually append some vars with the "with" but how do you call those vars from the templates original module is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @dibs those vars should be included on the original template context, if not then you have to inject them in the original template somehow depending on your needs for example by using `hook_preprocess_hook(&$variables)`, 
here is an example: 
`function my_module_preprocess_original_template_file(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['message'] = 'Hello world';
}`
Then in original-template-file.html.twig:
`{% include '@modulename/template-file.html.twig'  with {'var1': content.message} %}`
And finally in template-file.html.twig:
`<h1>{{ var1 }}</h1>`